# Location of three.js ColladaLoader source file

Tags: three.js, collada

I have been researching Javascript 3d programming. As such, I have learned about the THREE.js framework, and have had some success with it. Afterwards, I exported a Google Sketchup file I created (.skp) to Collada (.dae) and found some tutorials online that discussed ColladaLoader.js.

The examples stated things like the following:

```
<script src="three.js"></script>
<script src="ColladaLoader.js"></script>
```

Does this mean there is a ColladaLoader.js file out there for download? Just like there is a three.js file and a jquery.js file?

I have performed every google search possible and have not found an answer to this question, or the applicable source code file. I would really appreciate an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 15):

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/loaders/ColladaLoader.js